# Can't update my main JFrame from Key/Action Listeners in other classes

Tags: java

I'm a novice when it comes to Java programming. Hopefully you can provide me with an answer that can be implemented without too much difficulty. I'm writing a code that keeps track of how much money two persons are spending together.

I'm using a text file as a database and I've managed to read the file properly.

I have a main JFrame to which I add a JTabbedPane containing two JPanels. The JPanels are created with two separated methods that I have written in two individual classes. One panel has two JTextFileds in which the persons can write the amount spent after a purchase. The other JPanel is displaying the history and has a reset button that deletes all the data in the text file.

I've added a KeyListener to the JTextFields and an ActionListener to the JButton. Each Listener is written in separated classes.

Everything works just fine except the repainting of the main Frame. Now, I need to reopen the program to see the changes. I want to be able to repaint the main JFrame within the Listeners but I can't make it work.

This is the main Frame:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

static JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Reimbursment Control");   

public Frame() throws FileNotFoundException {

    JPanel c = ControlTab.getControlTab();
    JPanel h = HistoryTab.getHistoryTab();

    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    tabs.addTab("Overview", c);
    tabs.addTab("History", h);

    frame.getContentPane().add(tabs);

    //...
```

This is how I add the Listeners to the JTextFields and JButton:

```
ButtonClicked.addActionListener(button);
KeyPressed.addKeyListener(textfield);
```

These are the classes containing the Listener methods called upon above:

```
public class ButtonClicked {

public static void addActionListener(JButton button) {

    button.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {

                    //Here's code that deletes all the data in the file
                    //and it should be displayed right away but I don't 
                    //know how to update the main JFrame from here?

        }
    }
    );
}
```

...

```
public class KeyPressed {

public static void addKeyListener(final JTextField textfield) {

    textfield.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() { 

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {

                    //When pressing enter the value written 
                    //in one of the JTextFields will be entered in 
                    //the file which works but how can the repainting
                    //of the main JFrame be implemented here?                       

        }
    }
    );
}
```

Comment: In which class do you add the listeners?

Comment: Don't use a `KeyListener` on text field, use an `ActionListener`.  Some platforms may not use [Enter] for the action trigger

Comment: I have two classes containing one method each that create a JPanel that I implement in the JFrame. It's in these methods I add the listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need some kind model, which both panels can interact with.

The "control" panel would update the model with new information and the "history" panel would listen to the model for changes and update its view accordingly.

The is a basic [Producer/Consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) and [Observer pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) problem.

Consider your current example.  You attach listeners to the components and are notified of changes.  This is an example of the observer pattern.